# Inserting multiline text from file to another file after pattern

Tags: bash

I have files like:

> text2insert
>   filewithpattern

and also known:

> pattern

How can i insert lines from `text2insert` into `filewithpattern` but after the `pattern` line?

Using bash 2.05b

UPDATE:
Before `filewithpattern` should look like:

> garbage
>   pattern1
>   pattern2
>   garbage

and after:

> garbage
>   pattern1
>   text2insert lines
>   text2insert lines
>   text2insert lines
>   pattern2
>   garbage

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is the content after *pattern* deleted for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -e '/pattern/r text2insert' filewithpattern
```

Comment: It's wokring as i would like to. And it's short and simple. I like that very much. Thanks Dennis!

Comment: Is there a similiar script to insert the contents of `text2insert` *above* the line matched by `pattern`?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{      a[c++]=$0;next     }
/pattern1/{g=1;next}
/pattern2/{g=0;next}
g{ 
  for(i=1;i<=c;i++){
    print a[i]
  }
}' text2insert filewithpattern
```

And why do you need "garbage" in your output? Your previous question seems not to include "garbage"

Comment: last line should be like this? i mean... what is the `file`??

Comment: @kasper, `file` is `filewithpattern`

Comment: well garbage was just to make a point that there is something before and aftern pattern that shouldn't be touched by the script.