# Bash script to insert code from one file at a specific location in another file?

Tags: bash, shell, scala, scripting, sed

I have a fileA with a snippet of code, and I need a script to insert that snippet into fileB on the line after a specific pattern.

I'm trying to make the [accepted answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073014/inserting-multiline-text-from-file-to-another-file-after-pattern) work, but it's not, and is not giving an error so not sure why not:

```
sed -e '/pattern/r text2insert' filewithpattern
```

Any suggestions?

pattern (insert snippet on line after):

```
def boot {
```

also tried escaped pattern but no luck:

```
def\ boot\ {
def\ boot\ \{
```

fileA snippet:

```
    LiftRules.htmlProperties.default.set((r: Req) =>
        new Html5Properties(r.userAgent))
```

fileB (Boot.scala):

```
package bootstrap.liftweb
import net.liftweb._
import util._
import Helpers._
import common._
import http._
import sitemap._
import Loc._


/**
 * A class that's instantiated early and run.  It allows the application
 * to modify lift's environment
 */
class Boot {
  def boot {
    // where to search snippet
    LiftRules.addToPackages("code")

    // Build SiteMap
    val entries = List(
      Menu.i("Home") / "index", // the simple way to declare a menu

      // more complex because this menu allows anything in the
      // /static path to be visible
      Menu(Loc("Static", Link(List("static"), true, "/static/index"), 
           "Static Content")))

    // set the sitemap.  Note if you don't want access control for
    // each page, just comment this line out.
    LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(entries:_*))

    // Use jQuery 1.4
    LiftRules.jsArtifacts = net.liftweb.http.js.jquery.JQuery14Artifacts

    //Show the spinny image when an Ajax call starts
    LiftRules.ajaxStart =
      Full(() => LiftRules.jsArtifacts.show("ajax-loader").cmd)

    // Make the spinny image go away when it ends
    LiftRules.ajaxEnd =
      Full(() => LiftRules.jsArtifacts.hide("ajax-loader").cmd)

    // Force the request to be UTF-8
    LiftRules.early.append(_.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"))

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sed format looks correct to me.

To help you diagnose this, try it with two simpler text files and a simple pattern.

File filewithpattern:

```
hello
world
```

File textinsert:

```
foo
goo
```

Now run sed:

```
sed -e '/hello/r textinsert' filewithpattern
```

You should see this:

```
hello
foo
goo
world
```

Does that work for you?

If so, then edit filewithpattern to use your target:

```
hello
def boot {
world
```

Run the command:

```
sed -e '/def boot {/r textinsert' filewithpattern
```

You should see this:

```
hello
def boot {
foo
goo
world
```

If you want variable substitution, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATTERN='def boot {'
sed -e "/${PATTERN}/r textinsert" filewithpattern
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed for me too.  Going to build up filewithpattern to see where the problem is.

Comment: It's happening when I switch from hard coding 'def boot {' in the sed command, to replacing it with a variable $PATTERN or ${PATTERN}.  I could hard code it since the pattern won't change, but would be nice to set it in a variable at the top of my script with the other vars.  Any idea how to get that var to evaluate correctly in the sed param?

Comment: Post your code and I'll take a look. Likely it's a bash variable quoting issue.

Comment: I appended the answer with an example of variable PATTERN -- does it work for you?

Comment: Ah hah!  Double quotes around the sed string is the trick.  I was using single quotes there.  Everything works now, including the original full script!  Thank you soo much, I don't know how long it would have taken to figure that out.