# Using bash to insert data from array into file at specific location

Tags: bash, .htaccess, awk, sed

I am creating a script to populate an htaccess file with a blacklist. To do this I have used curl to download a blacklist, which I read into an array using a while statement, that way I can disregard lines that don't begin with 'deny'. Now I want to insert the elements from the array into the `.htaccess` file.

The array is called `DENY_DATA` and contains entries that look like this:

```
deny from 64.62.252.163
deny from 167.99.255.132
deny from 27.209.94.238
deny from 64.188.8.229
...
```

I have inserted two lines into the `.htaccess` file between which I want the deny statements to go. They look like this:

```
#~~~~~~~~~ BLACKLIST START ~~~~~~~~~~
#********* BLACKLIST END **********
```

I have tried the following using awk. However, this results in the tmp file containing only `${DENY_DATA[@]}` as a string.

```
awk '/^#~~~~~~~~~/ { printf "%s\n", "${DENY_DATA[@]}" }' .htaccess > tmp.file
```

I have also tried with sed as per [Inserting multiline text from file to another file after pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073014/inserting-multiline-text-from-file-to-another-file-after-pattern) and [Bash script to insert code from one file at a specific location in another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050330/bash-script-to-insert-code-from-one-file-at-a-specific-location-in-another-file). With this, I am left with the original htaccess file but no deny statements.

```
sed -e '/^#~~~~~~~~~/r printf "%s\n" "${DENY_DATA[@]}"' .htaccess > tmp.file
```

Is there a simple fix, or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the deny data in a file instead of reading it into an array, and then append the file after the blacklist start line with sed's [`r`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-r-_0028read-file_0029-command) (read file) command:

```
sed '/#~~~~~~~~~ BLACKLIST START ~~~~~~~~~~/r denydata' .htaccess
```

where `denydata` contains the deny statements.

If you have the data nowhere else but in the array, you can write it to a file first:

```
printf '%s\n' "${DENY_DATA[@]}" > denydata
```

Comment: Thats great, did the job. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to turn denydata into a variable so that I don't have to statically write the file location?

Comment: @Adam If you double quote the sed command, you can use shell variables; for example, assuming `$name` contains the name of the file you want, you can use `sed "/#~~~~~~~~~ BLACKLIST START ~~~~~~~~~~/r $fname" .htaccess`.